# Optimize performance of very wide tables in databricks delta

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Lately I've been working in a speculative machine learning space that frequently requires tables that are roughly a million rows long to be transposed. This can be done in a few hours in-memory, but I'd like to save the resulting transposition to a delta table. For some reason, write speeds are terrible - even trying to write one row with 1 million columns to a delta table to benchmark, I gave up after an hour. Yet one column with 1 million rows takes no time at all. Yes, columnar formats are going to handle the latter case better, but that much better? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: 1 million columns sounds like a lot.  Hard to tell if you should use a spark data structure, use array columns to have fewer columns, or do something else.  Posting a small, representative dataset, your transpose code, and your write code would help me give you a better answer.